# Call method in external class

Tags: php, api

How do I reference a method that is inside an external php file?

**external-file.php**

```
class OurExternalClient {
    public function getSomeData($variable) {
      $someCode = new Code();
      $someCode->variable = $variable;
      [...]
    }
}
```

**current-file.php**

```
include_once("external-file.php");

$moreCode = OurExternalClient::getSomeData($variable);
```

...I *figure* that is how I access an external method, but I'm not sure. When I do that, everything afterwards breaks. The example is quite vague, but I'm hoping I can get a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating an instance of the class?

```
include_once("external-file.php");

$OurExternalClient = new OurExternalClient();

$moreCode = $OurExternalClient->getSomeData($variable);
```

Comment: This looks like what I want. However, when I reference the method on the class (for example, the 3rd line in your code)... the rest of my code breaks. Why doesn't it like `->getSomeData($variable)` ?

Comment: When it breaks what happens? Do you get any errors?

Comment: First check is to make sure it's that specific line of code where the error is happening. Second, look at the code for the method you're calling - something in there will be causing the scrpit to stop.

Answer (score 1):

What you seek is the keyword "static". This way a "public static" functio can be called without an instance of the class.

Comment: Do I use the keyword "static" in the *current* file or the *external* file? This is for an API client.

Comment: Function u want to call should be static. Refer to the docs on php. net for that keyword

Comment: All the functions in the external class are public. I can't change them to static.

Comment: If u cant manipulate "ourexternalclient"  for some reason, u need to create an instance of it ($var = new ourexternalclient(); and then do $var->gwtdata（））